# Is there a web app that can take a snapshot of a public wiki and turn it into an offline help file like .chm?

Tags: webapp-rec

I'd love if there was an easy way to take a snapshot of a public wiki and turn it into a localized file. Preferably contained within a single file like a .chm, and not just a site rip of a large amount of .html files.

I know most wiki applications come with exports to PDF, and there's software out there that you can purchase which allows you to export to help files. I'm looking for an app that can do that without the necessity of the software.

This would be for a wiki I own, not any given one out there. Meaning I have access to the database / web files etc.

Comment: Your wiki or someone else's?  What wiki software?

Comment: @rchern My own. See the edit above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an [article](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/articles/gearsmonkey.html) on Google Code about how to add offline support to any web-page. The author used wikipedia as an example. There's a userscript which relies on Google Gears - a now-deprecated browser plugin. The script hasn't been updated for HTML5 (and perhaps never will) but it should work*.

[*] I haven't tried it myself though.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to take a further look at this. Though this looks more like a synchronization tool than a "snapshot" tool.

Comment: Accepted this one as I haven't found anything better yet, and I think I can use this to work around what I'm looking to do.

Comment: It's a very hard problem in general. I'm quite upset that snapshot support isn't built into MediaWiki. IMHO it should be because Wikipedia has them. Considering that most wikis use MediaWii as well that would ease things quite a lot. I can even imagine that snapshot support would have being viewed as an essential feature of wiki sites if that was the case.

Answer (score 0):

No Web apps an you would need a combination of tools to do it offline. Also most websites would prevent you from doing this. Most sites will protect their content from being able to be completely downloaded.

Comment: I'm talking more for a wiki that I run than any given one out there. Meaning I'd have access to the database and web files. I'll edit my question to reflect this.